# Is it possible to use a member of a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Following is a simple example.

```
template <typename TA>
class A {

};

template <class A>
class B {
    A a;
    A::TA ta;
};

int main(){
    B<A<int> > b;
}
```

where, I have a template class A with a unknown type (TA) as template parameter. In class B, I want to define some variables using class A and its member type.

I got an error message during compilation, as follows.

```
error: need typename before ˜C1::T1˜ because ˜C1˜ is a dependent scope
```

I know I can do something like this,

```
template <class A, typename TA>
class B{
    A a;
    TA ta;
};
```

But it seems an ugly format.

Is the first case possible? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the error message should be "error: need typename before ˜A::TA˜ because ˜A˜ is a dependent scope"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename TA>
class A {
public:
    using type = TA;
};

template <class A>
class B {
public:
    A a;
    typename A::type ta;
};
```

Does this help?

Comment: This declares a variable in class `A` for no reason. You can use `using type = TA;` in `A` instead and then use it as `typename A::type ta;` in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

An instantiation of your `A` template does not have *any* members. The template parameters *aren't* exposed outside the definition.

It's not clear if you want to use any type in B, or only instantiations of `A`. The latter is easier. Currently you are hiding the definition of `A` with your template parameter.

```
template <typename TA>
class A {
public:
};

template <typename TA>
class B {
public:
    A<TA> a;
    TA ta;
};
```

If you want to access the template parameters, `A` will need to expose them itself.

```
template <typename TA>
class A {
public:
    using some_name = TA;
};
```

Now `B` can use any type that has a `some_name` member type.

```
template <typename A>
class B {
public:
    A a;
    typename A::some_name ta;
};
```